# How to select specific attribute from yaml in python

Tags: python, yaml

I'm a beginner in python and trying to pull data from yaml file to use in a python script, say my yaml file looks like this:

```
---
genre: horror
film:
 -name: conjuring
 -id: 1234
film:
 -name: halloween
 -id: 1222
```

How would I select each part of the yaml, for example say I want the id of the film with the name halloween using python? I managed to read the file in by writing this:

```
import yaml

with open("films.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        code = yaml.load(stream)
        print(code.each)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

but that only gives me the following output and doesn't display everything:

```
{'genre': 'horror', 'film': {'-name': 'halloween', '-id': 1222}}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. You can't have two `'film'` entries.

Comment: @PeterWood ah ok, so what would be the best way to have multiple films defined in yaml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting duplicate keys in YAML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904290/getting-duplicate-keys-in-yaml-using-python)

Comment: That makes this a different question really. I've marked it as a duplicate as a quick search revealed this: [Getting duplicate keys in YAML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904290/getting-duplicate-keys-in-yaml-using-python)

Comment: ok cool, thanks for linking that and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can represent a list of films in yaml like this...

```
---
genre: horror
films:
- name: conjuring
  id: 1234
- name: halloween
  id: 1222
```

Answer (score 0):

As dekin notes, the problem is with your yaml syntax. You're providing duplicate entries for the key "film" rather than a list.

yaml lists should be of the format:

```
list_key:
    - item_1_field_1: foo
      item_1_field_2: bar
    - item_2_field_1: baz
      item_2_field_2: goof
```