# A pyyaml parser to list-ify values for the same key

Tags: python, parsing, yaml, pyyaml

I understand this isn't strictly valid YAML, but I'm wondering how I could modify my pyyaml parser to group the values associated with duplicate keys into a list.

So, I have the following:

```py
import yaml
from io import StringIO

data = """
NAME: Best Test
TEST: True

More: Yes

NO_LEADING_ZEROS: 0713

ENTITY:
    Name: Great
    Value: 10

ENTITY:
    Name: Even better
    Value: 11

"""

with StringIO(data) as f:
    parsed = yaml.load(f.read(), Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)
print(parsed)

assert(isinstance(parsed.get("ENTITY"), list))
```

I get the following:

```
{'NAME': 'Best Test', 
'TEST': 'True', 
'ENTITY': {'Name': 'Even better', 'Value': '11'}, 
'More': 'Yes', 
'NO_LEADING_ZEROS': '0713'}
```

Assuming I cannot change the "yaml" but only my parser, what would I change to get the following dictionary instead?

```
{'NAME': 'Best Test', 
'TEST': 'True', 
'ENTITY': [
  {'Name': 'Great', 'Value': '10'}
  {'Name': 'Even better', 'Value': '11'}], 
'More': 'Yes', 
'NO_LEADING_ZEROS': '0713'}
```

I've seen this answer which looks similar [Getting duplicate keys in YAML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904290/getting-duplicate-keys-in-yaml-using-python)

But that solution did not work for my use case, in that it just made every field into a list, and returned this:

```
{'NAME': ['Best Test'], 
 'TEST': [True], 
  'ENTITY': [defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
     {'Name': ['Great'], 'Value': [10]}), 
             defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
     {'Name': ['Even better'], 'Value': [11]})], 
'More': [True], 
'NO_LEADING_ZEROS': [459]})
```

Answer (score 1):

The question you linked gives a solution that needs only minor modification to do what you want:

```py
import yaml

def parse_preserving_duplicates(src):
    # We deliberately define a fresh class inside the function,
    # because add_constructor is a class method and we don't want to
    # mutate pyyaml classes.
    class PreserveDuplicatesLoader(yaml.loader.Loader):
        pass

    def map_constructor(loader, node, deep=False):
        """Walk the mapping, recording any duplicate keys.

        """
        mapping = {}
        for key_node, value_node in node.value:
            key = loader.construct_object(key_node, deep=deep)
            value = loader.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)

            if key not in mapping:
              mapping[key] = []

            mapping[key].append(value)

        for k,v in mapping.items():
           if len(v) == 1:
             mapping[k] = v[0]
        return mapping

    PreserveDuplicatesLoader.add_constructor(yaml.resolver.BaseResolver.DEFAULT_MAPPING_TAG, map_constructor)
    return yaml.load(src, PreserveDuplicatesLoader)
```

I removed the `defaultdict` since while it's useful for loading, you might not want everything to be a defaultdict. After constructing the `mapping` I added code that, if a key only had one value, removes the list surrounding the value. This gives you lists only for keys that actually occur multiple times.