# Not allow duplicate tags in yml file

Tags: json, perl, yaml

I am trying to validate my sample yml using yml schema file.

`a.yml` data file:

```yaml
    test:
         version1
    test:
         version1
```

`s.yml` schema file:

```yaml
     type: map
        mapping:
          test:
            type: str 
            required: yes
            unique: yes
```

In my perl code i am using YML inbuilt module and validate my data file with schema file as followed:

```
 eval { validate(YAML::LoadFile(s.yml), YAML::LoadFile(a.yml)) };
```

I was expecting to fail the validation because of having duplicate tags 'type:'. Is there a way to  not allow duplicate tags in yml file while validating against schema schema.

I notice that loading is failing with warning:

```
Name "YAML::SortKeys" used only once: possible typo at test.plline 21.
YAML Warning: Duplicate map key found. Ignoring.
```

Code: YAML_LOAD_WARN_DUPLICATE_KEY
Line: 1
Document: 1

Currently i am using 'use warnings FATAL => qw(all);', Still my script is passing. Not sure why it still pass with warnings.
Can we make it Error?

Comment: "I was expecting to fail the validation because of having duplicate tags 'type:'." - Do you mean `test:` instead of `type:`? Your `a.yml` contains only `test` keys.

Comment: Note, that `validate` is called on the YAML representation, which is obtained via `YAML::LoadFile`, and this **representation** does NOT have duplicate keys. It is `YAML::LoadFile` which consumes duplicate keys but silently **ignores** them (as most of libraries which reads YAML file do, see e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904290/getting-duplicate-keys-in-yaml-using-python)). For detect duplicate keys you need to find other methods of **loading** YAML, validation against a scheme doesn't help in that detection.

Comment: In order to detect duplicate keys what is the other way i could load?

Comment: Use a modern YAML module. See my answer. (And, by the way, YAML.pm is not a "builtin" module and also not shipped with perl)

Comment: If it helps, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[YAML::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::PP) forbids duplicate keys by default (*).

```
use YAML::PP;
my $yaml = <<"EOM";
foo: a
foo: b
EOM
YAML::PP::Load($yaml);

__END__
Duplicate key 'foo' at /.../YAML/PP/Parser.pm line 61.
```

You are using YAML.pm, which is not recommened anymore, as it was written for YAML 1.0 and also has other problems.

(*) YAML::PP forbids duplicate keys since version 0.027. Before they were ignored.