# Construct an object using ruamel

Tags: python, constructor, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I want to create some objects based on arguments in a yaml file. Everything was working fine, but now I want to supply the class with some options from which one should be chosen randomly. I thought I could use the `__post_init__` method for this, but the learned, that this is intentionally not called because the use case is to serialize and deserialize objects.

Is there a way to tell ruamel to use the constructor of the class and call `__post_init__`?

This is almost what I want, but I couldn't get it to work with ruamel despite it saying that it was tested using ruamel at the bottom:

- [Answer on SO: Is there a way to construct an object using PyYAML construct_mapping after all nodes complete loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35476888/6411540)

My current setup is like this:

```py
import random

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object

yaml = YAML()

@dataclass
class A(ABC):
    some_var: str
    options: list[str]

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.other_var = random.choice(self.options)

@yaml_object(yaml)
@dataclass
class B(A):
    yaml_tag = "!B"
    more: int

@yaml_object(yaml)
@dataclass
class C(A):
    yaml_tag = "!C"
    foo: list[int]

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        self.bar = random.choice(self.foo)

# …
data = yaml.load("config.yml")
```

yaml to load:

```yaml
test_classes:
  - !B
    some_var: abc123
    options: ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
    more: 7
  - !C
    some_var: abc123
    options: ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
    foo: [7, 12, 42]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your YAML document consists of a single unquoted scalar `config.yml` , and that loads
as the Python string `config.yml`. You can easily check that by doing `print(repr(data))`
at the end of your program. And for that you don't need to define dataclasses.

If you want to load the contents of the file `config.yaml` you should do:

```
yaml.load(Path('config.yaml'))
```

Please note that the recommended extension for documents containing YAML files has
been `.yaml` since at least September 2006.

Using `@yaml_object(yaml)` on your dataclasses doesn't give you any option to
make `yaml_object()` call `__post_init__()`. For that you need to
use the "normal" registration, or provide a `from_yaml` classmethod that does that.
However if you pre-construct the dictionary, you can create
the dataclass with the constructed values:

```py
import random
from pathlib import Path

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass

from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object

yaml = YAML()

@dataclass
class A(ABC):
    some_var: str
    options: list[str]

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.other_var = random.choice(self.options)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        # wrong, but cannot do better with dataclasses without defaults
        data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()  
        constructor.construct_mapping(node, data, deep=True)
        return cls(**data)

@yaml_object(yaml)
@dataclass
class B(A):
    yaml_tag = "!B"
    more: int

@yaml_object(yaml)
@dataclass
class C(A):
    yaml_tag = "!C"
    foo: list[int]

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        self.bar = random.choice(self.foo)

data = yaml.load(Path("config.yaml"))
print('other_var:', data['test_classes'][0].other_var)
print('bar:', data['test_classes'][1].bar)
```

which gives something like (your result can be different because of the randomly picked values):

```
other_var: Y
bar: 42
```

Note that `from_yaml` as presented is not the right way to handle non-scalar
nodes. What it should do is something like:

```
@classmethod
def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
    res = cls()
    yield res
    data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()  # wrong, but cannot do any better
    constructor.construct_mapping(node, data, deep=True)
    res.update(**data)
    res.__post_init__() # now the data to choose from is there
```

But `res = cls()` fails, as you cannot make instances of `B()` and `C()` without providing the attributes (that
have no defaults).

For your config file this will only become a problem when there are (indirect) self references in the input YAML
document (i.e. when using achors and aliases). When you need those I recommend you change the code and add defaults so that `res = cls()`
will work.